# I can not find for the source code repository for poi-ooxml-schemas

Tags: apache, apache-poi

Alright, this is a little bit wierd. I've checkout apache-poi version 3.9 source code from
http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/src/
But I can not find the source code for poi-xml-schemas. I have been googling but to no avail. Where is the code repository for these project? Is it a separate project from the poi source code or it is from some other project used as a library, but where is the code repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is covered in the [Apache POI FAQ (#14)](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10109), from which I quote:

> **14. I can't seem to find the source for the OOXML CT.. classes, where do they come from?**
>
> The OOXML support in Apache POI is built on top of the file format XML Schemas, as compiled into Java using [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Currently, the compilation is done with XMLBeans 2.3, for maximum compatibility with installations. (You can use the resulting classes on the XMLBeans 2.3 runtime, or any later version of XMLBeans. If you are currently using XMLBeans 2.2 or earlier, you will unfortunately have to upgrade, but this isn't common any more).
>
> All of the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006 CT...` classes are auto-generated by XMLBeans. The resulting generated Java goes in the *ooxml-schemas-src jar*, and the compiled version into the *ooxml-schemas jar*.
>
> The full *ooxml-schemas* jar is distributed with Apache POI, along with the cut-down *poi-ooxml-schemas* jar containing just the common parts. The source jar isn't normally distributed with POI. It is, however, available from Maven Central - ask your favourite Maven mirror for the *ooxml-schemas-src* jar. Alternately, if you download the POI source distribution (or checkout from SVN) and build, Ant will automatically download the specification XML Schema, and compile it for you to generate the source and binary ooxml-schemas jars.

Comment: And here the convenience link to one of central maven repo mirrors: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/

Comment: It should be noted that at the time of writing this comment, there are no sources for the ooxml schemas CT.. classes on maven central. The self-building approach works, but is imho more cumbersome than it would need to be (compared to just downloading the sources).

Comment: As the FAQ points out, the source is generated from the ECMA spec which can be found here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm.

Answer (score 2):

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.0/

has the ooxml schema ----- CTArray jar files.

Comment: ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar   has all the CT jar files