# The source code for poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 is not available for download.. Where to find it?

Tags: java, maven, jar, apache-poi

Hi i am looking for the source code for ***poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 version*** and i can't find it anywhere. 
All the other POI jars do have the source code jar available for download but this one seems to have it missing. 
Need this as for some Open source clearing of jars in my project.
at one place i found the complete source code of poi (https://downloads.apache.org/poi/release/src/) but it is not of much help.

I was not able to find the source code for older versions of poi-ooxml-schemas as well.

Comment: See if the below links answers your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358701/i-can-not-find-for-the-source-code-repository-for-poi-ooxml-schemas

Comment: ya thanks it does help a bit .. I found the answer in http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10109 (Apache FAQ 15 ).

Comment: they don't provide the source code for poi-ooxml-schemas but do have the complete source code as ooxml-schemas (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/)

Comment: Source of the full schemas is provided, as linked. Because of how the cut-down `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar is generated (but running the unit tests with tracing enabled and tracking which classes were touched), there's no easy way to get the source of just that bit. However.... It's all auto-generated by Apache XMLBeans from the Microsoft XSDs, so the source doesn't really matter that much!